# Vertical alignment of ul in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I've been struggling for the entire day to center the `ul` list with the `id="menu"` vertically in this responsive layout.

Would really appreciate a hand getting in in the right place. I Want it to be centered vertically to the right. The list consists of circles indicating where you are in a one page scroll layout and also functioning as navigation.

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">1</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">2</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">3</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="1"><p>O</p></div>
<div id="2"><p>O</p></div>
<div id="3"><p>O</p></div>
<div id="4"><p>O</p></div>
<div class="section " id="section0">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <p>Hihi</p>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <p>Hihi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="intro">

            <h1>Simple</h1>
            <p>Hihi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Hey</h1>
            <p>Hihi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Heyhey</h1>
            <p>Hihi</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <p>Hihi</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section3">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <p>Hihi</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0;    
}

ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    font-family: arial,helvetica;
    color: #000;
    color: rgba(246,192,6,1);
}
.wrap{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}
h1{
    font-size: 6em; 
}
p{
    font-size: 2em;
}
.section{
    text-align:center;
}

#1 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 70;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

#2 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 70;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#3 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 70;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#4 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 70;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}


#menu li {
    display:;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: #000;
    background:#fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    width: 35%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 35%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#menu li.active{
    background:#000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
    color: #fff;
}
#menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
}
#menu li.active a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
#menu li:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
    padding: 9px 18px;
    display:block;
}
#menu li.active a{
    color: #fff;
}
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C55wX/2/)

Comment: this is not answer: you have problem in your code : check first li you have closed a div tag there

Comment: it's better to provide a fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle Hashem! I guess what I want is to vertically center my ul.

Comment: I don't think that you want to align `#menu`. It is already on the right. See the box in this update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C55wX/1/. Do you want to align the 0 in the divs after `#menu`? These are not part of `#menu` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is not being applied "}" is missing from this rule.

```
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Numbers should not be used as a ID tag.

This is a perfect place to do vertical centering using full html5 with CSS3 transform, which will center anything vertically.

```
#menu {
position:fixed;
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%); /* for chrome preview */
right:0;
height: auto;
z-index: 70;
width: auto;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: if the element has specific `height` its better to use negative margin instead of `transform:translateY`

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian Normally yes, but in this case the (see jsfiddle) he is using a position:fixed, which works like position:absolute and margin-top:-20px; is not centering with top:50%. Vertical aligns can be a real pain with all the different display and position types, transform once it is fully supported across all browsers will solve these problems. However, IE8 will be with us for awhile. Great thing about mobile devices is they support it.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you want something like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C55wX/3/).**

I added the border so that you can see the ul is aligned to the right.
You want the `div` numbered elements to be part of the ul. So, the first code is now:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage"><div id="1"><p>O</p></div></a </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage"><div id="2"><p>O</p></div></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage"><div id="3"><p>O</p></div></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage"><div id="4"><p>O</p></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

Actually, what I think you want is something like this: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C55wX/5/)**.

Note the change from `p` to `span` the new class `bulletDiv` and the addition of vertical-align middle:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><span id="1" class="bulletDiv">O</span><a href="#firstPage">1</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><span id="2" class="bulletDiv">O</span><a href="#secondPage">2</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><span id="3" class="bulletDiv">O</span><a href="#3rdPage">3</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><span id="4" class="bulletDiv">O</span><a href="#4thpage">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.bulletDiv{
    font-size: 2em;
    vertical-align:middle;    
}

#menu li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```